# Как я могу получить градиент свойство из класса и поместить его в другой массив С #

Tags: c#, json, uwp

***есть джсон в нем есть 3 класса то что мне нужно gradientprops находиться в tittle который свою очередь находиться в классе Class1 как мне оттуда получить gradient и поместит в другой массив после чего мне нужно это показать на uwp  через клик
Возможно, я неправильно сформулировал свой вопрос, но я думаю, что проблема заключается в следующем: как включить gradientprops в мою коллекцию?
gradientprops, который дольжен отобразится в listview, получает null  может
с структурей класса что то не так или коллекцию нужно поменять как то но не как не мог что то изменить.
Я хочу использовать datatemplateselector, чтобы получить следующее:
когда я отмечаю изображения в разделе, отображаются изображения, когда градиент _ в разделе показывает градиенты _, когда цвет в разделе цвета***

**Main Page**

```
Class1[] mycollection = null;
  
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            string FilePath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Class1.json");
            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(FilePath))
            {
                var json = file.ReadToEnd();
                Class1[] rootobject = (Class1[])JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Class1[]));  
                foreach (var item in rootobject)
                {
                    mycollection = item.details;
                    

                    

                }

              
            }   
        }
```

**Class1**

```
 public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Class1
    {
        public string itemType { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public Detail[] details { get; set; }
       
    }
    public class Detail  :Class1
    {
        public string detail_type { get; set; }
        public string itemType { get; set; }
        public string fill_color { get; set; }
        public Gradient_Props gradient_props { get; set; }
        public string icon_url { get; set; }
        public string resource_url { get; set; }
    }
    public class Gradient_Props 
    {
        public string gradient_stop_1 { get; set; }
        public string gradient_stop_2 { get; set; }
    }
```

**Class DataTemplateSelector**

```
public class MyDataTampletSelector : DataTemplateSelector
   {
        public DataTemplate Details { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate Gradient {get; set;}
        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item )
        {
          
            if (item is Gradient_Props)
                return Gradient;
            if (item is Detail)
                return Details;
            return base.SelectTemplateCore(item);
        }
   }


   }
```

**XAML**

```
 <Page
    x:Class="Task2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Task2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GradientItemTemplate" x:DataType="local:Gradient_Props">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind gradient_stop_1}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DetalisItemSelection" x:DataType="local:Detail">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind icon_url,Mode=OneWay}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind resource_url , Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <ColorPickerSlider Name="{x:Bind   fill_color   , Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
        <local:MyDataTampletSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector"
        Details="{StaticResource DetalisItemSelection}"
         Gradient="{StaticResource GradientItemTemplate}">
        </local:MyDataTampletSelector>
    </Page.Resources>
    <ListView x:Name = "MyListView"
          ItemsSource = "{x:Bind  mycollection}"
          ItemTemplateSelector = "{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}">
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

**json**

```
[
    {
        "itemType": "Canvas",
        "type":  "Color",
        "title": "gen_color",
        "details": [
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ffffff"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#feffdf"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#fdffab"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#fff9af"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#f9ff21"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ffd933"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ffbd39"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ff8000"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#f05a28"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#f12d2d"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ff0000"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#defcfc"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#a6e3e9"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#7efaff"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#53cde2"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#26baee"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#2470a0"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#235784"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#1b3764"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#4a0e5c"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#5e227f"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#a8026f"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#d22780"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#ff5da2"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#fa67ab"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#f48fb1"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#f9a1bc"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#c7f2e3"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#9ed9c5"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#73dbc4"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#1abb9c"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#219897"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#155e63"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#00454a"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#003545"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#28544b"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#227066"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#4a772f"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Color",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "fill_color": "#7cbd1e"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "itemType": "Canvas",
        "title": "effect_color_gradient",
        "details": [
        
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#002092",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#1AB9C8"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#F75070",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FFE194"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#2B0096",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#E9649B"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#5A63D8",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#CD90E1"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FDE869",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#00B1C1"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FECF60",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#974EF6"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FFD529",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FD8440"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#C24078",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FFC3B9"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#00EAF8",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#6D42EF"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FF90D3",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#3AEF3C"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FFCD2C",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FF0663"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FC1E50",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#D2B0EF"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#EF14C5",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FFC160"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#7AE4FF",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FC2F5D"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#6CF6DA",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#176DA0"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FF0467",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FC7437"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FD8041",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FF4CA1"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#FEB984",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#FF5542"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#00FAC1",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#C500E1"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#6FFF00",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#005BFF"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#F8A2ED",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#934EAE"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#5F86EC",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#7C4CB0"
                }
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Gradient",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "gradient_props": {
                    "gradient_stop_1": "#EB4B92",
                    "gradient_stop_2": "#CA76E3"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "itemType": "Canvas",
        "title": "win_pattern",
        "details": [
        
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_1.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_2.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_2.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_3.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_3.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_4.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_4.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_5.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_5.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_6.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_6.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_7.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_7.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_8.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_8.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_9.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_9.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_10.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_10.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_11.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_11.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_12.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_12.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_13.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_13.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_14.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_14.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_15.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_15.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_16.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_16.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_17.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_17.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_18.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_18.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_19.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_19.jpg"
            },
            {
                "detail_type": "Pattern",
                "itemType": "Canvas",
                "icon_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/icons/i_bg_20.jpg",
                "resource_url": "http://pastatic.picsart.com/backgrounds_ver7/2048/bg_20.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Тесно связан с этим вопросом**
[Как сделать десерилизацию json?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-json?noredirect=1#comment2039004_1172869)